# How to hide/display default Image

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, slds

I have an image tag :

```
<img src="{!v.ticketDetails.url}"  alt="Image not found" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

If image is not found, it shows broken Image icon on chrome.
However this works with plain HTML but not working in lightning component.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images.jpeg" onerror=" this.style.display='none'">
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve same functionality in lightning component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me. In lightning world, you cannot use inline javascript instead everything has to be handled by controller functions.

**HelloWorldApp.app:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <img src="images.jpeg" onerror="{!c.imageError}"></img>
</aura:application>
```

**HelloWorldAppController.js:**:

```
({
    imageError: function(component,event,helper){
         event.target.style.display = 'none';
    }   
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct DOM manipulation(especially on the DOM the framework manages) inside the controller is not recommended.

Though you can use the `$A.util.addClass()`,`$A.util.removeClass()` to achieve the same.

Quote from the doc:

> You can modify CSS classes for a component outside a renderer by using
>   the $A.util.addClass(), $A.util.removeClass(), and
>   $A.util.toggleClass() methods.

Eg:

**component:**

```
<aura:component>
   <ui:button label="Toggle" press="{!c.toggle}"/>
   <p aura:id="text">Now you see me</p>
</aura:component>
```

**controller:**

```
({
    toggle : function(component, event, helper) {
       var toggleText = component.find("text");
       $A.util.toggleClass(toggleText, "toggle");
    }
})
```

**css:**

```
.THIS.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

Please refer the section on [Modifying the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_dom_access.htm) in the LC dev guide.