# Fallback for missing image in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

This is same question as [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159298/how-to-hide-display-default-image), but for lwc.

What I've tried so far is

```
<object data="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" type="image/png">
    <img src={it.value.img} alt={it.value.alt} style="max-height: 16px;" />
</object>
```

To no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I had it backwards,  is where requested image href should be and fallback is the img tag inside.